# Subir adjuntos con un input file en SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar subir un adjunto (por ejemplo una imagen) con input file, y enviarlo por chat a través de SignalR, El problema es que falla al intentar serializar el formData, debido a que no se envía de forma correcta el dato, ¿cómo se podría solucionar?

Este es mi código:

**.aspx**

```
    var blobFile = $('#fuAdjuntos')[0].files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fuAdjuntos", blobFile);
    chatHub.server.sendMessageToAll(userName, msg, date, idUsuario, $('#hdId').val(), null, formData );
```

**.cs**

```
      public void SendMessageToAll(string userName, string message, string time, int idUsuario, string idChat, string usuarioDestinatario, object formData) 
      {
        byte[] byteFile = datos.SerializarArchivo(formData);
        Clients.All.messageReceived(userName, message, time, UserImg, usuarioDestinatario, byteFile);
      }

    public byte[] SerializarArchivo(object formData)
    {
         byte[] byteFile = null;
         if (formData != null)
         {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bf.Serialize(ms, formData);
                byteFile = ms.ToArray();
            }
         }
         return byteFile;
    }
```

Comment: no se envian files por SignalR, con este a los sumo notificaras al cliente que tiene un mensaje y sera quien vaya a tomarlo con algun otro servicio que retorne la imagen

Comment: Igual la imagen la subes a tu servidor, y llevas control de quién la mando y a quién en una base de datos, así cuando llegue el mensaje a la otra persona puedes recuperar la imagen. Incluso podrías guardar el historial de mensajes en la base de datos.